# remove multiple files with same extension in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I moved my code from Xcode on macOS environment to Visual Studio C++ on Windows. I used to remove several files with same extension without any issue on Xcode macOS by

```
system("rm -f toto_folder/*.txt");
```

Now, on Visual Studio C++ I tried

```
remove("toto_folder\\*.txt");
```

but in vain. Any help?

Comment: The [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove) doesn't mention anything about placeholders. But C++ offers a better library than the stuff inherited from C: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you could delete files with the same extension by calling cmd.

```
std::string command = "del /Q ";
std::string path = "path\\directory\\*.txt";
system(command.append(path).c_str());
```

Quietly deletes all files in the supplied directory. If the /Q attribute is not supplied then it will confirm delete for every file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works fine to me. But these lines seem to delete even other files with other extensions (.dat) so is there anyway to choose wich extension remove and keep the others ?

Comment: I run the code and only delete `.txt`. The `.docx` and `.xlsx` are reserved. So, could you show me what you input? It will be helpful to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid resorting to `system()` (which is not portable and not great for performance), you will have to read the contents of a directory using [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator), and check for each file in it whether it matches the pattern. C++ doesn't have a [`glob()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) function, so you generally speaking have to use something else, like  [`std::string::ends_with()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/ends_with) or [`std::regex_match()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match). However, if you just have to check the extension, it is relatively easy:

```
for(auto const& entry: std::filesystem::directory_iterator{"toto_folder"}) {
    if (entry.extension() == ".txt")
        std::filesystem::remove(entry.path());
}
```